# Report Preview PDF not working in 4.7.6

Tags: wordpress, civireport, 4.7.6

We are finding that a membership report and Preview PDF often goes to a page not found error. It seems to depend on the fields selected -- the fewer fields then better chance of getting a PDF to appear. What is the advice or guideline for this feature? Can we preset the page format to landscape to allow for more columns?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the page format is the issue, it's more likely an issue about custom fields. There have been recent changes (due to security issues) with how custom fields are being handled, I'd update to the latest 4.7 before pursuing further.